# SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL with Google Cloud's SSL Load Balancing Proxy

Tags: sockets, ssl, google-cloud-platform, proxy

I have a simple python SSL server behind a GCP SSL Proxy Load Balancer (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/) set up as per the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl/) with the exception that the server runs on a single node in an instance group of one. The GCP SSL proxy can connect to the server as I see a lot of empty health check requests that the server prints. DNS for the node name mypocketxp.com points to the static IP I attached to the proxy's forwarding rule. When I connect with the client below or with 'openssl s_client -connect mypocketxp.com:443' the server crashes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server3.py", line 13, in <module>
    sslsoc = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 776, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1036, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 648, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:877)
```

When I remove the proxy from the equation, and change the DNS entry to point directly to the node running the server and replace the self-signed certificate and key with the certificate and key issued by a trusted CA for mypocketxp.com I can connect without a problem.

So it seems that the connection from the SSL Proxy to the server is causing the problem but I have no idea why.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for looking into this

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="/home/adittmer/selfsigned.pem", keyfile="/home/adittmer/selfsigned.key")

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('', 443))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    sslsoc = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    request = sslsoc.read()
    print(request)
```

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import ssl

server_name = 'mypocketxp.com'
server_port = 443

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations("/etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem")
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), server_hostname=server_name)
conn.connect((server_name, server_port))

conn.send(b"Hello, world!")
conn.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried to configure [Session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Yes, I did and it did not make a difference. Also, there is only a single back-end server so I did not think that that would be the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Please provide me more details about your use. Why do you need a load balancer with only one backend server?

Comment: This a test setup. I want to get this to work first before scaling out and while experimenting things are easier just with a single back-end node

Comment: Just to make this clear again ... The real weird thing about this is that the server code with the trusted certs works as expected without the SSL proxy in the middle. Thanks again for looking into this

Comment: Strangely enough I got this to work after shutting down the Python server and spinning up and connecting to an nginx server from my laptop and then retrying, indicating that the problem may be related to a state of the Load Balancing infra.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this message when I've just setup the load balancer and immediately requested a HTTPS page from it. It seems that the LB takes a while to start up. Trying again 5 minutes later and this problem clears up for me.